# Wordpress remove_filter wpautop custom wysiwyg

Tags: php, html, wordpress, function, hook

How do I go about using this hook for custom wysiwygs?

I have tried this:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter('the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```

Thats what i usually use for the default wordpress content editor but it doesn't work with Advanced Custom Fields Wysiwyg?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind have found the solution!

**Simply do this:**

```
remove_filter('acf_the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter('acf_the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```